# How to decrypt using Public Key

Tags: cryptography, encryption, rlpx

Can anyone decrypts cipher-text using Public Key? as I know we can only decrypt using private key, but in this  [RLPx documentation](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/wiki/RLPx-Encryption) what this line means?

`Receiver receives the initiator handshake and decrypts it with its own public key.`

are they talking about verifying signatures?

Comment: To me, the entire paragraph that you referenced makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be an error. The decryption is with the node's own private key. See the [code here](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/blob/462180064e33fbbca758ccb4c8f771064e90470f/p2p/rlpx.go#L346) (which calls the actual decryption [here](https://github.com/ethereumproject/go-ethereum/blob/462180064e33fbbca758ccb4c8f771064e90470f/p2p/rlpx.go#L465)), quoting the comment 4 lines above:

```
// prv is the local client's private key.
```